# Chrome won't render font-weight for Google Web Font correctly

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts

I've searched a lot on here and found nothing with the exact same issue I was experiencing, so I'm starting a new thread.

Developing a site using the Google Web Font "Muli" which has a Light 300 and a Normal 400 weight. I've linked the web font stylesheet with the weights included correctly directly from Google Fonts as follows:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:300,400,300italic,400italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I know all my code is correct because they render correctly in Firefox and Safari.

Does anyone know if this is a known bug in chrome? And if so is there a workaround?

Comment: Have you tried `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased`?

Comment: I did try that. It does smooth the text but it does not make the correct weights show. I would include pictures but being a new user here it will not allow me to do so.

Comment: Gotcha. What about promoting the text element to a new layer using `transform: translateZ(0)`?

Comment: Nope that had no effect either.

Comment: You should include a minimal document that actually reproduces the problem. A mere `link` element does not produce anything. And “not correctly” is not a problem description; explain what was expected and how the actual rendering differs from it.

Comment: A simple test with `p { font-family: Muli }` and with two `p` elements, one with `style="font-weight: 300"` shows that Chrome uses Muli Light, which is visibly different from regular Muli.

Comment: Chrome also has difficulties with other, non-web, fonts. Where Firefox and even Internet Explorer show light and regular as expected, Chrome does not play along. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/r6Um5/). (You may have to change the font family to one that you have installed on your computer.)

Comment: @JoshRutherford Sorry, but what did you expect "promoting the text element to a new layer" to solve? That doesn't have anything to do with how fonts are displayed. Also, Chrome needs the `-webkit-` prefix.

Comment: Actually promoting a layer will change it from grayscale antialiasing to subpixel antialiasing. Sometimes this can help. Check this article: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/antialiasing-101/

Comment: @JoshRutherford How odd; I had no idea. Thanks for enlightening me!

Comment: @MrLister no worries, I just stumbled across this as well :)